# How to render "If I have told you once, I have told you a thousand times" into French

Tags: expressions

> **If I have told you once, I have told you a thousand times**–you’d better tell her soon, or some other guy will come along and snap her up!

To express this idea  in French, in conversation I said:

> **Je te répète pour la énième fois** : tu ferais bien de te dépêcher, sinon un autre type va te la souffler !

This English phrasing is a humorous way to say frustratedly:

- *No matter how many times you try to get some advice or warning through the thick skull of someone, you are left with nothing to show for your efforts.*

How is this idea effectively expressed in French?

Answer (score 2):

Non-native here, but if my French wife has told me the following once, she's told me a thousand times (with & without the parenthetical):

"Combien de fois dois-je te le dire (avant que ça n'entre dans ton crâne)?"

Comment: That looks like a literal translation of "How many times do I have to tell you before it gets into your thick head?", which is another common way to express this in English.

Answer (score 1):

La liste des manières d'exprimer ton sentiment est énormément longue, et doit aussi dépendre de la personne à qui tu t'adresses et de ta relation avec elle. C'est pourquoi j'ai précisé (entre parenthèses) pour ces petits exemples, ce que *je* pense être le sentiment associé à chaque phrase.

1. Je te l'ai déjà répété 100 (ou 1.000 ou 10.000) fois (moralisateur / accusateur).
2. Ce n'est pas comme si je te l'avais déjà répété 100 (ou 1.000 ou 10.000) fois... (moralisateur / réprobateur)
3. On n'a qu'à faire comme si je ne te l'avais jamais dit ! Mais... (plutôt sarcastique)
4. Est-ce que je t'avais déjà dit qu'il valait mieux [ dire / faire / te dépêcher ] ? (plutôt **très** sarcastique si tu l'as effectivement déjà dit à cette personne)
5. Si tu le fais avant la [Saint Glinglin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Glinglin), tu auras peut-être une chance... (très moqueur)
6. Sinon, tu peux aussi attendre qu'un autre te l'ai soufflée et aller lui demander (moqueur).

Comment: Hi. What do you think of: "*Ça fait je ne sais combien de fois que je te le dis : tu ferais bien de te dépêcher, sinon ...*"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens : I like it ;) but sounds like father -> son IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to express this, I suggest a few more :

- Je te l'ai dit et redit : tu ferais bien de te dépêcher, sinon un autre type va te la souffler !
- Je te l'ai déjà dit mais j'en remets une couche : tu ferais bien de te dépêcher, sinon un autre type va te la souffler !